# A question about calculus

Tags: calculus

$\displaystyle\int_{ \mathbf Q} s^a \, dm $

I don't know how to start at all. Can anyone give me some hint how to calculate integral in this type?

Comment: May I ask about the reason why you [deleted a copy of this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/823567/11619) and reposted it today?

Comment: Oh yes!I think that title is confused and misleading, so I gave it a new title. Since " with m a p-Adic measure" is very unclear.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: You may try partitioning the integration domain as 
$$
\Bbb Z_p\times\Bbb Z_p=\bigcup_{i\in{\cal I}}A_i
$$ 
where the function you are integrating is constant on the open-closed subdomains $A_i$. For instance, since $||xy(x+y)||=||x||\cdot||y||\cdot||x+y||$ you may take each $A_i$ inside some 
$$
(p^r\Bbb Z_p\setminus p^{r+1}\Bbb Z_p)\times(p^s\Bbb Z_p\setminus p^{s+1}\Bbb Z_p)
=p^rU_p\times p^sU_p
$$
where $U_p$ is the multiplicative group of units.
With this, the problem essentially boils down to computing the measure of each $A_i$.